# Check if key/value is present in json

Tags: python, json

So, here's what I am trying to do.

Given key and value, I am trying to see if both are present in json.

for eg: I got this json from response

```
{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}
```

The code should return True only if both key and value are in json(response)

```
key: name
value: John
```

In this case the response should be TRUE

```
obj = json.loads(json_string) #response_json
key = body.get("key")  #gets_key
value = body.get("value") #gets_value
```

Comment: *any* value or the value corresponding to the key?

Comment: `key = body.get("key") ` does not "get the key". It returns the value associated with `key` (or `None`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test whether the key `"name"` has the value `"John"` in your `obj` dict, you'd do:

```
return obj.get("name") == "John"`
```

In the above example `"name"` is the key (it's the argument to `get`) and `"John"` is being compared to the value that is returned by `get`.

Note that `return` only has meaning within a function body (i.e. this code should be part of some larger `def` statement that defines a function).

In your original code, `body` hasn't been defined, so I'd expect `body.get` to raise an error.  Calling `obj.get("key")` would return the value associated with a key called literally `"key"`, and `obj.get("value")` would get the value associated with a key called `"value"`.  I don't think either of these are what you want.

If you wanted to use variables called `key` and `value` that would look more like:

```
key = "name"
value = "John"
return obj.get(key) == value
```

Note that when we're referring to a *variable* called `key`, we use the variable name without quotes; that's what differentiates a variable from a string literal (`key` is a variable called `key` that can reference any string or other object we assign to it, `"key"` is the actual specific string `"key"`).